# Java calling Object.notify() before Object.wait()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, wait

i have 2 thread one for transmissions and one for replay 
I would like to send one message only when i receive a message on the RXThread. i've used wait() and notify(), and for preventing that a notify came before the wait() i do this, but it only works when run in debug, although the RX thread doesn't send the message.

```
private boolean stopped = false;


class StubTxtask implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {

            // Sends all messages in sequence
            for (int i=0; i<txMsgSeq.getMessagesCount(); i++) {
            }
                if (syncRxTx) {
                    synchronized (syncObj) {
                        while(!stopped) {
                            syncObj.wait();
                    }
                    }

                }
                System.out.println("************ "+ i + "/" + txMsgSeq.getMessagesCount());
                pcs.sendMsg((GeneratedMessage)txMsgSeq.getMessage(i));
                if (!syncRxTx) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}


class StubRxtask implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Wait for a message() 
                TncMessage msg = (TncMessage) pcs.waitMsg(connInt);
                System.out.println(msg.toString());
                // Add the message to the RX Sequence
                rxMsgSeq.addMessage(msg);

                System.out.println(rxMsgSeq.getMessagesCount());

                if (syncRxTx) {
                    TncHeader header;
                    Method invokeGetHeader;
                    try {
                        invokeGetHeader = msg.getClass().getMethod("getHeader", null);
                        header = (TncHeader) invokeGetHeader.invoke(msg, null);
                        if (header.getType() != EnumMessageType.ACK) {
                            synchronized (syncObj) {
                                stopped = true;
                                syncObj.notify();
                            }

                        }


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("ERROR - Impossible to find or invoke getHeader() method on msg");
                    }


                }
                stopped = false;

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it only works fine in debug, this usually happens because of timing issues, which are different in debug mode.

As far as I understand your code, the use of a [Phaser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) would satisfy your requirement. A phaser is like a Barrier: it causes all threads to wait until all threads are waiting on it, except that it is reusable. Since now both threads are waiting till the respective other has arrived, you no longer need your `stopped` construction nor the synchronized (all is handled by the Phaser internally).

Replace

```
if (syncRxTx) {
  synchronized (syncObj) {
    while(!stopped) {
      syncObj.wait();
    }
  }
}
```

with

```
if (syncRxTx) {
  phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
}
```

And

```
if (header.getType() != EnumMessageType.ACK) {
  synchronized (syncObj) {
    stopped = true;
    syncObj.notify();
  }
}
```

with

```
if (header.getType() != EnumMessageType.ACK) {
  phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
}
```

Note: As always with synchronization objects, the Phaser should be declared final.

Answer (score 0):

Use Semaphore for synchronization instead, as these kind of locks handle "early notify".

```
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);

runConsume() {
  .. sem.aquire(1); // will block if nothing avaiable
}

runProduce() {

  // receivedMessage
  .. sem.release(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use variable in `while` loop in another thread and want to get fresh data you must declare it with `volatile` ( Check `visibility` rule)